# Saving username information to a server instead of NSDefaults (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, post, user-data

I have a server for storing username and password data in my application. When testing the app I had everything save to the device locally using NSDefaults, but now that the app is close to being fully launched, I am trying to save them to the server instead, as it is safer that way for the user's information.

When I had it save to NSDefaults, it was easy and short work. Now however, I am trying to POST the data to the server and keep getting build errors. What do I need to change for this to work? Am I not fully understanding how POST and GET works? Thanks. Using Swift 2 as of right now, not my choice, I prefer 3, but my boss isn't letting us update it yet.

The current error is coming from the POST USER DATA TO SERVER section, where xcode claims that userNmeTxt cannot be converted into NSData. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Error is on line 87: "Cannot convert value of type UITextField! to expected argument type NSData!"

```
import UIKit

class UserNameViewController: AuthorizationViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var userNameTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var continueBtn: UIButton!

var userModel: ProfileModel!

//MARK: - SYSTEMS METHODS

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    userNameTxt.delegate = self
    userNameTxt.autocapitalizationType = .Sentences
    setEnabledButton()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = getBackButton()
    self.title = ""
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    continueBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
}

override func popToRoot(sender:UIBarButtonItem){
    self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}

//MARK: - CHECK FOR AVALABILITY

func setEnabledButton(){
    if userNameTxt.text == "" {
        continueBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    } else {
        continueBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 63.0/255.0, green: 220.0/255.0, blue: 236.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    continueBtn.userInteractionEnabled =  userNameTxt.text != ""
}

//MARK: - POST USER DATA TO SERVER

func postData(url: String, params: Dictionary<String, String>, completionHandler: (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {

    // Indicate download
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    let url = NSURL(string: "myPlaceholderURLgoesHere")!
    //        print("URL: \(url)")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    // Verify downloading data is allowed
    do {
        request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error in request post: \(error)")
        request.HTTPBody = nil
    } catch {
        print("Catch all error: \(error)")
    }

    // Post the data
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        completionHandler(data: userNameTxt, response: userModel, error: error)

        // Stop download indication
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        // Stop download indication

    }

    task.resume()

}

//MARK: - SEGUE

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toPassword"{
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! PasswordViewController
        controller.userModel = userModel
    }
}

//MARK: - IB ACTIONS
@IBAction func continuePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    userModel.userNickName = userNameTxt.text!
    performSegueWithIdentifier("toPassword", sender: self)
}
}

extension UserNameViewController: UITextFieldDelegate{
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.setEnabledButton()
}
}
```

Comment: In case you're not aware of it, you may want to consider storing preferences in iCloud Key-Value store with `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud.html

Comment: First, don't store the password in NSUserdefaults without at least encrypting it separately.  At least try to protect your users' security.  Also, storing credentials on the server seems odd.  When you register for the account, the credentials should be stored (protected with encryption using a credential specific salt: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Use_a_cryptographically_strong_credential-specific_salt).  When the user enters their credentials on the device, you should hit the web service to validate the credentials, no need to re-save.

Comment: If you are saving credentials for convenience, you should store it in the Keychain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to change.

`userNameTxt` is not the username, it's the UITextField containing the username.  The text you need is `userNameTxt.text?`

If the function is expecting Data, you have to convert your text to Data first

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
    completionHandler(data: userNameTxt.text?.data(using: .utf8), response: userModel, error: error)
```

Comment: Had to adjust your code slightly to work for our code, but that fixed the problem! Thank you! It's my first job and I'm the only iOS dev at the startup so I've been a bit mentally exhausted lately and didn't even catch that I was trying to use the actual TextField!

Comment: Happy to help.  Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have to send the data to the server.

If you don't have too you can save the data in keychain access, see: [SO: Keychain Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459879/how-to-store-a-string-in-keychain-ios)

In order to resolve the error please edit the question with the error message and line of code (if possible).

I would suggest that you use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for POST/GET (REST). To use Alamofire you need basic knowledge of Cocoapods. It's better in the long term.

NOTE: There can be two possible error outcomes when you make the request.

1) Incorrect data format or bug from your side

2) Server error due backend bug from server side.

The data can be sent from your device with POST where the data is in the BODY or HEADER of the request. Usually it is in the body (parameters in the alamofire methods).

Here is an example:

```
import Alamofire 
...

// MARK:- Login Feature - Universal Met for login
internal static func loginWith(serverUrl: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, headers: [String: String]?, notificationName: String, serviceType: LoginService)
{
    Alamofire.request(.POST, serverUrl, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON
    { (response) in
        print("\n Login feature - \n")
        print(" Login url - \(serverUrl)\n")
        print(" Login parameters - \(parameters)\n")
        print(" Login notificationName - \(notificationName)\n")
        print(" Login response - \(response)\n")
        EXCDataParserH.parseResponseFrom(ServiceType.Login(type: serviceType),
            operation: nil,
            data: response.data,
            notification: notificationName)
    }
}
```

Comment: I gave the answer to @Russell because he solved the issue posted in my question, but your response is great! Will definitely be checking out Alamofire now, as it is a lot simpler than my messy server side code is. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the whole thing every time you make a server request, try to do as follows:

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

class HTTPHelper{
class func httpPostDataDic(postURL:NSURL,postString:NSString,completionHandler:@escaping (NSDictionary?, NSError?) -> Void ) -> URLSessionTask{
    var responseResultData: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:postURL as URL);
    request.httpMethod = "POST";// Compose a query string
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue);
    print(request)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(error)")
            completionHandler(nil, error as NSError?)
            return
        }
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        if let responseString = responseString {
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }
        do {
            let myJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            responseResultData=myJSON!
            completionHandler(responseResultData, nil)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    return task


}
}
```

Now whenever you need to make a server POST request,in your ViewController class, do as follows:

```
//Requesting server
func requestServer() -> Void{
    let postvariable = "Value"

    let url = URL(string: "your url")!
    let postString = "postkey=\(postvariable)"
    HTTPHelper.httpPostDataDic(postURL: url as NSURL, postString: postString) {
        (responseResult, error) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if error != nil{
                print(error ?? "unknown")
            }
            else{
                print(responseResult ?? "unknown result")
//Parse your response
                self.parseResult(result: responseResult!);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

May I ask you one thing that I didn't understand in your question.
How exactly would you save the login credentials in a server? I mean, if you save the login credentials in the server, how would you authenticate user access to these saved credentials?